# when focus on the pre-test for the normality test and ignore the pre-test for equality of variances?

Tags: normality-assumption

When should a pre-test for normality only without a pre-test for equality of variances be performed before location tests like this paper did ((Rochon, J., Gondan, M. & Kieser, M. To test or not to test: Preliminary assessment of normality when comparing two independent samples. BMC Med Res Methodol 12, 81 (2012). https://doi.org/10.1186/1471-2288-12-81))

Whereas, other papers focus on the two pre-tests for normality and equality variances before location tests such as ((Rasch D, Kubinger KD, Moder K: The two-sample t test: pretesting its assumptions does not pay. Stat Papers. 2011, 52: 219-231. 10.1007/s00362-009-0224-x.)).

my question is when focus on the pre-test for the normality test and ignore the pre-test for equality of variances, and when we focus on both pre-tests for normality and equality of variances?

Comment: My opinion: Don't do any formal hypothesis tests for "assumptions". See [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/is-normality-testing-essentially-useless) on normality testing to get a few ideas why it's usually ill advised.

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/551264/when-to-check-model-assumptions  for an answer to a more general question, and for a very special case see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/434928/unequal-variance-in-randomized-experiments-to-compare-treatment-with-control