When should statistical tests be pre-specified in a study, and what are the risks of selecting tests post hoc?
In several resources and discussions, I have come across recommendations that statistical tests should be pre-specified before conducting an analysis, particularly in confirmatory research. I understand the idea behind reducing bias and the potential for "p-hacking," but I am curious to explore this further.

Are there specific research contexts where pre-specifying tests is always necessary? For instance, in clinical trials or regulatory research, I assume there are stricter rules, but are there other contexts where this also applies?

How does exploratory analysis fit into this? In situations where data is being explored to generate hypotheses, is it acceptable to choose tests after data inspection, provided the process is transparent?

Finally, I would appreciate an explanation of the consequences of choosing statistical tests post hoc. I have seen references to issues like "Type I errors" and loss of statistical validity, but I would like to better understand the mechanics of how selecting a test based on data can lead to false positives or other issues.

Any references to relevant literature would be appreciated as well!



You don't use the term in your question, so I guess you might find informative to look for the forking paths problem. Here is a recent thread about it, for example: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/649886/164936

Closely related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/310119.

The 'consequences' are usually discussed in an implied framework of the all-or-none hypothesis tests and error rates of Neyman & Pearson. That is not the only framework and it is, arguably, the least suitable framework for many scientific studies. See this chapter for a discussion of the differences between the error rate framework and a more evidence-based use of p-values. It includes a section on the issues of multiple comparisons that you will likely find helpful. https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/164_2019_286

The problem with the term "acceptable" is that it depends on the persons who are asked to "accept" something or not. Deciding which test to run based on the same data on which the test is then run will invalidate the theory on which the test is based. However it is in general not clear how harmful this actually is. Arguably model assumptions are never exactly fulfilled in reality anyway, so one may wonder if it does less harm to look at the data and then to decide something that seems to look right for the data in hand rather than to run a pre-specified analysis that turns out to be grossly inadequate actually looking at the data.
Unfortunately it is hard if not impossible to make general statements about this. In fact situations can easily be constructed in which choosing a test dependent on the data is actually very harmful (for example if in a linear regression you kick out all variables that are insignificant and you re-run the model with significant variables only, the p-values and absolute values of the parameter estimators of these variables in the resulting model can be strongly biased), but on the other hand situations in which a pre-specified test is misled by some features of the data that could be easily detected looking at the data such as gross outliers exist as well. In such situations it can easily be better to deviate from what was pre-specified.
Some discussion, a literature review and results regarding testing model assumptions before running a model-based test are in this paper of ours.
Unfortunately, it is not even possible to know in all cases what the consequences are (because that would rely on the underlying true distribution, which may have relevant features that cannot be identified from the data in hand), and whether consequently one should or should not change the analysis based on the data, for which reason it is really very subjective what is "acceptable" and what isn't.
One intuitive criterion is that making data-based decisions will be less harmful if the way the decision is made is as far as possible independent/"orthogonal" to the analysis that is then done conditionally on the earlier decision. This can be argued pretty well for example in linear regression for decisions that are made based on the residuals only, as the residuals are in the standard model independent of the parameter estimates. On the other hand, making decisions based on the very same statistic that is later of interest (like the regression parameters themselves or p-values associated to them) will likely lead to trouble.
Exploratory data analysis can be very good at understanding what goes on in the data, and consequently at deciding what statistical method to use. But a major issue with this is that due to its subjective nature it cannot formally be analysed how good or harmful it actually is. This will also strongly depend on who makes the decisions. And of course this person needs to convince the audience that these decisions have been made not in the first place to push a specific message or "achieve significance", but properly to use knowledge from the data in order to avoid misleading results.
It seems better, if there is a possibility to do that, to do exploratory analysis including a decision about what method (test, say) to use on data different from those on which the resulting test is then run, but from the same process. If you have enough data, you can just split your data set. In this way, the finally selected method is not affected by the earlier data-dependent decision making (note that this technically requires independence and identical distribution between the two parts of the data).
Indeed I believe this is an essential hard problem with statistics, as essentially we have to decide whether we fly blind (using a pre-specified method not checked against the data) or we invalidate the standard model assumptions of our methods by making data dependent decisions. Both is not optimal, but this is the situation in which we are.
