Checking the logistic regression assumptions with classic goodness-of-fit tests
Whilst searching for ways to check the model adequacy after estimating the coefficients, I found out that I need to i) check for logistic regression assumptions and ii) check for the goodness-of-fit.
When I say goodness-of-fit I don't mean testing the predictive power (I do that with McFadden Pseudo R^2). I want to check how well the estimated values represent the observed data.
Resulting out of that, my question: When a gof-test is telling whether you could do even better by making the model more complicated, which is actually testing whether there are any non-linearities or interactions that you have missed, is it the same as testing all of the assumptions? So in short: Is it necessary to test the assumptions separately, by using e.g. lowess smooth (smoothed y) or do alternatives to the HL-test test the same?
And as a result: for my model, which consists of a single continuous explanatory  variable (and a binary outcome) with a sample size of 10, which test would be most appropriate? Because of my small sample size, the  standardized Pearson is not suitable. Another measure could be the Stukel test. Would love your thoughts on this!

Note that in general formal tests for model misspecification are not necessarily a good tool for such decisions. For example, a misspecification test might reject a model assumption even if the violation is rather mild and the model is still very good at doing its job. Misspecification tests generally don't address the question whether and how a model can be improved. (I'm not saying you should never run misspecification tests, but the issue of model assumptions is more complicated than "don't use model if test rejects, otherwise we're fine.")

Sample size 10 is very low for detecting anything, and also very low for fitting a more complex model with more parameters.

I've written some general thoughts about model assumption checking here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/551264/when-to-check-model-assumptions/593587#593587

I would go farther than @ChristianHennig regarding sample size of 10. A usual rule of thumb for logistic regression is that you  want 10 observations in the less common category for each IV.  You have a maximum of 5 in each category. You want at most one IV.

And, with only 10 observations, you really won't be able to see , much less test, any violations. There just won't be enough evidence.

@ChristianHennig I've read your post about model assumptions, thank you! So my learnings are to check the model assumptions (even if it has little informative value) and perform a gof-test seperately to check how well the estimated values represent the observed data. You say that formul tests are not a good tool. Would you mind sharing what would be a good tool to check the assumptions for my situation? (again:even if it has little informative value)

@PeterFlom Thank you for your input! Do you happen to have a reference that explains the 'rule of thumb' of 10 observations for each IV? Additional info: I have a model with 6 observations Y=0 and 4 obs. with Y=1.

I'm not saying misspecification tests are never a good tool. They are not perfect and somewhat problematic but nothing perfect exists, so it's really complicated to give general recommendations. Unfortunately I tend to agree with @PeterFlom that with your number of observations it's pretty hopeless to do something that makes sense, regarding assumption checking.

Here is a Wikipedia article about the rule of thumb. of one in ten
