When regression models outperforms the naive methods?
I followed from this question.

Case1:
I have the following task to do: Training by the consecutive 3 days to predict the each 4th day. Each day data represents one CSV file which has dimension 24x25. Every datapoints of each CSV file are pixels.
Now, I need to do that, predict day4(means 4th day) by using training data day1, day2, day3(means three consecutive days), after then calculate mse between predicted day4 data and original day4 data. Let's call it mse1.
Similarly, I need to predict the day5 (means 5th day) by using training data day2, day3, day4, and then calculate the mse2(mse between predicted day5 data and original day5 data)
I need to predict day6(means 6th day)by using training data day3, day4, day5,  and then calculate mse3(mse between predicted day6 data and original day6)
..........
And finally I want to Predict day93 by using training data day90, day91, day92,calculate mse90(mse between predicted day93 data and original day93)
I want to use Ridge regression, Linear regression and LSTM model. And we have 90 mse for each model.
Case2:
Here I am using,  is known as "the" naive forecast, or a "random walk" forecast. It is often hard to beat.
Naive approach is:
The guess for any day is simply the map of the previous day. I mean simply guess that day2 is the same as day1, guess that day3 is same as day2, guess that day4 is same as day3,....., guess that day91 is same as day90. I mean Predict next day's data using current day's data(predicted_data = current_day_data). Then calculate mse between next_day_data and current_day_data.
Results:

In case1, I observe that, It is extremely common for very simple methods(regression models) to outperform complex ones(lstm) in low data situations. This is satisfying as expected. Simple methods will be especially competitive in low data situations. "Competitive" quite simply means "lower prediction error".

In case2, we know naive method often very hard to beat, means lower MSE,  but it is outperformed by simple regression approach in case1.



My questions:

In which situation would one simple regression model(in case1) outperform a naive method (in case2)? I mean, how to know specifically why one simple method outperforms another naive one on my specific dataset?

how to dig my data set to understand one simple method outperforms another?


My data sample for example the day1,day2,day3,day4.

Each MSE is calculated this way : we have one error (more accurately called a residual): the difference between the true and predicted values. The mean squared error(MSE) would be the mean of those squared differences, and we get one per model.

@Sycorax Is the LSTM only using day 1, day 2 and day 3 to predict day 4?- yes. By the way I have understood LSTM issue. Main question is about "random walk" forecast(naive method ) and regression models. How and why simple regression models outperforms naive method? We know that naive method is often hard to beat. But in my case I get exception.

Is the mses shown in the picture computed on holdout data?

@Ggjj11 would you elaborate more what you want to ask?

I just wonder how "reliable" the MSE values in the figure are: if you split the dataset (possibly repeatedly) and estimate your model on one part of the data and evaluate it on another part of the data, this is where you may get unbiased performance estimates (on this holdout part)...

@Ggjj11 no, I get the same result always.

Cross-posted at https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/130661/55122 and https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/47207/21542

@Ggjj11 would you able to write some thoughts based on my current scenario that I described in question, otherwise my bounty will be wasted. I want to give bounty.

It will always depend on the specific data set and situation. I'd say there is no better option to find out than using cross-validation, bootstrap and the like, i.e., checking how well held out data are predicted, if necessary adapted to the specific situation, e.g., time series.

@ChristianHennig would you write your opinion as an answer, I really grateful to you.

OK, done, but there isn't more to it right now than in my comment.

The answer I am going to give is quite general, but I think it may help you. One common and simple reason why a 'naive' forecast outperforms 'simple' regression models as well as 'complex' ones is that there is no structure to learn. In your specific case, you train w.r.t. the MSE, so what your model is trying to approximate is the conditional expectation of the observation at time $t$, say $Y_t$, conditional on $(Y_{t-1},Y_{t-2},Y_{t-3})$. So the object of interest is $\mathbb{E}(Y_t|(Y_{t-1},Y_{t-2},Y_{t-3}) = \vec{y})$. Now if $\mathbb{E}(Y_t|(Y_{t-1},Y_{t-2},Y_{t-3}) = \vec{y}) = y_{t-1}$ you have a simple random walk. Your models are trying to approximate this behavior while the naive forecast exactly reflects this behavior. If the structure is linear, i.e.
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(Y_t|(Y_{t-1},Y_{t-2},Y_{t-3}) = \vec{y}) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 y_{t-1} + \beta_2 y_{t-2}+ \beta_3 y_{t-3},
\end{align}
then a linear model will perform best. If the structure is a complicated function, a LSTM model will perform best. The question you always have to ask yourself is 'what is my model trying to learn?' (in my opinion). The way you can find out if there is structure and what is may look like is to use descriptive statistics! For linear relation in the first moments consider the (partial) autocorrelation function ((p)acf). For non-linear relations you may look at scatterplots of $Y_t$ and $Y_{t-h}, h \in \mathbb{N},$ or use more sophisticated dependence measures such as kendalls $\tau$.
Another comment which is related to the answer: Keep in mind that when you train w.r.t. the MSE, you also only train your model to learn a relation in the first moment. There may be structure in the second moment but with training w.r.t. the MSE your models won't learn it. This is common in e.g. daily financial time series where the ARCH (or GARCH) models perform well in learning the structure in the second moments (aka conditional volatility) but there is not much to learn in the first moments (all parameters of an fitted ARMA are not significantly different from zero). However, if you are interested in the mean-forecast only, this won't help you.

Would you elaborate with example? Then it will help me lot. Thank you.

One example is the random walk itself! Then you have $\mathbb{E}(Y_t|...) = Y_{t-1}$. Another example would be white noise (what you possibly get if you take first differences of a random walk), where you have $\mathbb{E}(Y_t|...) = 0$. A more interesting example is the AR model, i.e. $\mathbb{E}(Y_t|...) = \phi_1 y_{t-1} +...+\phi_3 y_{t-3}$. For more complicated functions there are countless examples.

"There may be structure in the second moment "-- would you explain which structure you want to mean?

Your last line "However, if you are interested in the mean-forecast only, this won't help you."-- would you elaborate more?

It will always depend on the specific data set and situation. I'd say there is no better option to find out than using cross-validation, bootstrap and the like, i.e., checking how well held out data are predicted, if necessary adapted to the specific situation, e.g., time series.

Would you elaborate in general in which conditions simple regression models outperforms naive methods? By the way I  appreciate your opinion.

@S.M. Obviously a simple regression model will be good if the real process is well described by it. These methods have assumptions and they will work well if the assumptions are not violated in a critical way.

What do you mean by "critical way"? By the way  your answer are really good, but need your more explanation. Thank you.

@S.M. That's a rather subtle and complicated issue and depends on what exactly you do. "Critical" general means that some violations of model assumptions will lead to misleading results (and may deteriorate prediction performance). I wrote some stuff here about this, but this may not address your specific situation: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/551264/when-to-check-model-assumptions/593587#593587

In final question, what is my violations in  model assumptions(regression models)? And how to correct way to do this?
